# Como diminuir letras google charts

Tags: javascript, html, google-charts

Olá, gostaria de saber como personalizar as letras do Google Charts, tenho um gráfico gerado, porem os nomes estão grandes, então não aparecem todos, alguém sabe uma maneira de diminuir as letras ou então, colocar as palavras tombadas?

[image: Relatorio, nem todos os nomes la embaixo estão aparecendo]

Segue o código

```
     var options = {

            chart: {
                title: 'Relatorio Geral',
                subtitle: 'Quantidade de Operarios por função',
            },

            chartArea: { width: '100%', height: '50%' },
            annotations: {
                textStyle: {
                    fontName: 'Times-Roman',
                    fontSize: 18,
                    bold: true,
                    italic: true,
                    // The color of the text.
                    color: '#871b47',
                    // The color of the text outline.
                    auraColor: '#d799ae',
                    // The transparency of the text.
                    opacity: 0.8
                }
            }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a documentação você pode usar textStyle. 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart#Configuration_Options

```
var options = {
  annotations: {
    textStyle: {
      fontName: 'Times-Roman',
      fontSize: 18,
      bold: true,
      italic: true,
      // The color of the text.
      color: '#871b47',
      // The color of the text outline.
      auraColor: '#d799ae',
      // The transparency of the text.
      opacity: 0.8
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: tentei fazer com isso e não deu certo.

Comment: Poderia editar a mensagem e postar o seu código?

Comment: Pronto, coloquei o código na pergunta

Answer (score -1):

Para texto na vertical:

```
              hAxis: {
                   title: "",
                   slantedText: true,  /* Enable slantedText for horizontal axis */
                   slantedTextAngle: 90 /* Define slant Angle */
                   
              }
```